# JQuery - Adding commas to number inputs but not on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I know of a JQuery plugin that adds commas to your number inputs such as [JQuery Number Format](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format/178/), but in my testing the data becomes invalid because the numbers have been converted into text and there are two situations I'm trying to overcome:

1. When the data submits to the DB it's recorded as text because of the comma's placed in the data (MySQL DB using Varchar for the column)
2. When the data is used in a calculation (either data pulled from DB or function using inputs data not pulled from DB)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to format numbers with comma's, but the comma's are removed for calculations and on submit? There is nearly 100 places this needs to take into account, so a scalable method is preferable.

Comment: I don't know PHP. Get it as text. Split it based on comma. Append all values together. Convert the data into Number and then Do whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow the form to submit the input value even though it still contains the commas, just process it in the server-side to remove the commas:

**PHP**

```
$input = $_POST['input'];              // e.g. '1,000,000'
$input = str_replace(',', '', $input); // $input == '1000000'

// other operations (maybe save it to db?)
```

Comment: This is awesome, do you know how to do that with javascript as well? Sometimes the calculations are done with data not pulled from the DB but also from inputs with values that is changing in real-time.

Comment: @dvoutt I think this already works for your situation, because `$input` in there is already from the input fields in your form that got submitted to the server.

Comment: Good point I'll try this all out later tonight thank you very much.